# ApplicationContentUriRules section

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

Can anyone explain what's the purpose of the ApplicationContentUriRules section in the Windows 8 manifest file? What should happen when I add a new URI in that section? Will it be executed as if it's in the local context? The docs say it's used for allowing external content to be loaded in iframe, but that's completely wrong. Can someone please provide a definitive answer on what's the purpose of this section?

Answer (score 1):

It's used to allow specific pages in the web context (which are generally pages external to your app) to access certain native features - like geolocation and the clipboard - that they normally would be unable to access. It essentially provides a whitelist.